# When redirecting a process' both Input and Output in Windows, input doesn't work

Tags: c++, c, winapi, pipe

I want to redirect the Input and Output of a program, to another program which uses two threads, one for Input of the process, another for output. Now the 2nd program reads from it's stdin and writes to the 1st program's stdin. Similarly, 2nd program reads from the 1st program's stdout and writes it to it's stdout. And, I do this using anonymous pipes[CreatePipe()]

I've followed the logic from this link: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx)

But, so far what I've been able to achieve is that I can get the stdout properly redirected, but when it comes to redirecting the stdin, scanf() functions don't wait to get the input, they just simply takes no input!

My questions is: What could be the problem? is it a Win32 API specific problem?
or a common redirected related issue? or is it a buffering related problem?

I've even kept this article in mind: [Be careful when redirecting both a process’s stdin and stdout to pipes, for you can easily deadlock MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110707-00/?p=10223)

Note:
 In the 2nd Program I've used two threads for the I/O redirection. One for Input and one for Output. And, through a "pretty ugly trick", I've been using PIPE HANDLE as FILE*.

P.S.: This is my first question in stackoverflow. So pardon me if I've violated any rules for making questions.

EDIT:
that program whose I/O I've redirected:

```
char name[256];
char school[256];
int age = -1;


strcpy(name, "(_null)");
strcpy(school, "(_null)");

printf("What's your name?\n");
int n = scanf("%s", name);
printf("\n\nscanf()=%d\n", n);    //this prints -1

printf("What's your age?\n");
scanf("%d", &age);
```

And the two thread routines that I used to perform I/O redirection:

*rdpipe->m_stdout* and *rdpipe->m_stdin* are both of types *FILE* from stdio.h, but *m_stdout* is **read-only** and *m_stdin* is **write-only**.

```
bool fexit = false;

void func_out(RDPIPE *rdpipe) {
    char buf[1024];
    while(true) {
      fgets(buf, 1024, stdin);
      if(fexit) break;
      fwrite(buf, 1, strlen(buf), rdpipe->m_stdin);
      if(fexit) break;
    }
}

void func_in(RDPIPE *rdpipe) {
   char buf[4096];
   while(!feof(rdpipe->m_stdout)) {
       int n = fread(buf, 1, 4096, rdpipe->m_stdout);
       fwrite(buf, 1, n, stdout);
   }
   fexit = true;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What value does `scanf` *return*?

Comment: Nice question. I haven't tried that ... let me see...

Comment: scanf() returns -1(that's EOF) i don't know why.

Comment: if -1 returned look `errno` value.

Comment: it's an EOF but it isn't supposed to be